# Accessing Chatter API in Communities

Tags: community, chatter, permissions

I'm Having trouble accessing the Chatter API in the context of a community. Mainly, we have a certain type of user that only has access as a user of a SalesForce community we are using to act as an Identity Provider.

We have enabled 'Allow API Access' on the user profile, and the community seems to have chatter enabled. However, calling an API endpoint like https://.force.com/services/data/v36.0/connect/communities/internal/chatter/users with a Bearer token returns the following

```
403: Forbidden 
{
  "message": "The Chatter Connect API is not enabled for this organization or user type."
  "errorCode": "API_DISABLED_FOR_ORG"
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas on what I could be missing

Comment: which edition is yours?

Comment: I am operating on a Full Copy sandbox of a Unlimited Edition organization.

Answer (score 2):

See the documentation for [Connecting to Salesforce Communities](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/quickstart_communities.htm)

You need to do the following, both when authenticating and accessing /chatter/users:

- Replace "https://.force.com" with the full path to your community eg https://[communities_custom_domain_name].force.com/[community_name]

your communities custom domain name can be found by viewing the **Communities Settings** Page, which you can search for in the setup menu

Comment: this setting is only available in dev orgs according to sfdc support

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the exact cause of the problem, but in `/connect/communities/internal/chatter/users`, "internal" needs to be replaced with the ID of the community the user belongs to. Using "internal" refers to the internal network, which your community user does not belong to.

Also, does GET /services/data/v36.0/connect/communities return the same HTTP 403 error?

Comment: /services/data/v36.0/connect/communities returns the same HTTP 403 error

Comment: How about /services/data/v36.0/sobjects ? This will narrow down whether it's a general API problem, or a Connect API problem.

Comment: Strange, looks like the /services/data/v36.0/sobjects returns a invalid session 401 error. However, using the same bearer token for the /services/data/v36.0/connect/communities endpoint gives that 403 error.

The OAuth2 token I am using is the one generated by Rails Omniauth's access code grant to the particular community. Note: the user that is logging in is an external identity user, could there be API limitations through that?

Strangest of all, if I an enable the chatter tab for the community, I can manually edit their image and have that be returned during the Oauth2 exchange.